# How do I make a Drupal.ajax call manually?

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I need to be able to load a Drupal node via ajax, which I was able to get working using the "Ajax Link (Renderable Array)" from the Example module. The example module code does the ajax call and response processing automatically, but I want/need to be able to do it manually...how would I go about doing this?

I'm able to make the ajax call using jQuery and I get back a valid json response so the server side is working. Can I used this json response and call something in Drupal's ajax.js library to process the response or can I use ajax.js to make the call and therefore process the response automagically?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

what i did, when i faced the same problem is as follows:
i added the following anchor to my page:

```
<a id="some-id" class="use-ajax" href="" style="display:none;" >you cannot see me</a>
```

and since the anchor has the use-ajax attribute i know it is added to the Drupal.ajax array.
next, in my javascript code i manually preformed the ajax call like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              url: "THE_URL_TO_YOUR_MENU_CALL",
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                          Drupal.ajax['some-id'].success(data, textStatus);
                       }
            });
```

and it worked for me.
i think that what you are missing is the `Drupal.ajax['some-id'].success(data, textStatus);` line of code in your code.
hope i have answered your question...